# Why isn't my CSS taking effect on a textarea?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I can't figure out why none of the CSS I am using is having an effect on a textarea. The textarea's id is "addquestion", which is what I'm using in my CSS, but to no avail. Inline CSS works, but not through my separate stylesheet. I can verify that the stylesheet is definitely linked correctly because there is another element that is working just fine, its just this textarea that isn't being affected.

```css
#addquestion {
  width: 20px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  background-image: url(bg.gif);
  background-position: bottom right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<form>
 <div class="section">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
       <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="addquestion" style="width:20px;" placeholder="Find this for me..."></textarea>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group" id="addtags">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Tags">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group" id="addmoney">
       <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Amount (to the nearest dollar)">
      </div>
     </div>     
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <input type="file" id="main_upload_file">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="section">
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
   <a class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Submit</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure there's no other tag with the same *id* in the page?

Comment: @watery just did a ctrl+f on the entire code and found no other match. There is only one.

Comment: Are you seeing this in all browsers? (which one are you testing?)

Comment: it worked for me [http://jsfiddle.net/2oyf11o0/](http://jsfiddle.net/2oyf11o0/)

Comment: @Carsten testing on Chrome

Comment: Ah, there seems to be a problem when modifying specifically a textarea. I tested some obvious CSS changes to the other elements and they worked fine. On the other hand, inline styling works fine on this textarea, but is that recommended? I'm really very curious as to why using CSS in a child theme's style.css does not have an effect on textarea....could it be a problem with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing #addquestion to textarea in your css file. Unless you have other textareas, of course.